# Difference between public static nested class and public class?

Tags: java, class

what is the difference of `apple` class in the following cases?

```
public class fruit {
  public static class apple {

  }
}
```

v.s.

```
public class apple {

}
```

Both of them can be access outside of the class and both can be instantiated.

When to use which? Thank you!

Comment: It's really just a naming structure, in practice they behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

Most typically you want to use a regular `public class`, but if there is a `class` that you expect to be used very rarely, or if you need a hidden class as an implementation detail, the `static class` can be used there.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as you said, both can be used outside, but assume you have some group of related info that you know they are under the same type, for example

```java
public class Groceries {
   public static class Fruit {}
   public static class Vegetables {}
   ...
}
```

This way you can group a couple of models (classes) under same parent model, however you should always ask yourself two simple questions;

> Is that will be fine with the client who gonna use this class? Will the
> maintenance for this class be easy if include such static class inside?

You should also keep in mind the performance impact for such usage, `static` fields are always being loaded while the application starting up.

If you found yourself staisfied with this go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 0):

A public static nested class has visibility of private members of the enclosing class.  This is not available to regular top-level public classes.